# Unicode character showing as ? in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, unicode

I tried to query some Unicode content in MySQL to NodeJS page.
I tried to set db and table collate to utf8_general_ci.
This is how my connecting creation looks like:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                host     : helpers.config.database.host,
                user     : helpers.config.database.username,
                password : helpers.config.database.password,
                database : helpers.config.database.database,
                charset : 'utf8_general_ci'
                });
```

But almost the unicode characters become '?', Any solution for this?

This is how it looks -

[image]

Comment: Try using only utf8

Comment: charset : 'utf8' still return ?

Comment: Try utf8_unicode_ci. If it works, let me know. I will add it as an answer :)

Comment: Are you sure that your database/table uses utf-8? The standard is latin1_swedish_ci and this one can't handle utf-8.

Comment: @Joerg by standard you mean mysql default value right?

Comment: `utf8_general_ci` is not a ***charset***, it's a *collation*. The charset you typically want is `utf8mb4`, or `utf8` if you're on a very old MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

You should also set charset in response as follows. Check if your database/table uses utf8 as @Joerg suggested first.

```
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
```